# Is it possible to install Microsoft Office 2020 on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, 20.04, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I recently downloaded PlayOnLinux and it only offers MS Office 2000/2003/2007/2010/2013/2016. I probably shouldn't say "only" it's plenty, but can I install the 2020 version?

Maybe not useful but I am a student and I have a free MS Office pack that contains all Office programs in the 2020 version but I can't download it on Linux, only on Windows and Mac. It would be pretty cool if there was a way to download Office 2020 on Ubuntu.

Btw I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Set up a windows virtual machine.

Comment: The folks who develop and maintain Wine WINEHQ.COM have not yet documented if it works. When it appears at https://www.winehq.org/search?q=Microsoft+Office+2020 then you'll know if it's possible. Until then, Organic_Marble's suggestion is viable, or you can see if LibreOffice (included with Ubuntu) or other Linux-based Office Suites are suitable. See https://www.g2.com/products/libreoffice/competitors/alternatives for a list.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks! I don't know how I forgot about that...

Comment: @crodev it is a pain, but works the best.

Comment: Maybe using bottles is the option for you